# Cannot use Near() due to schema lock

Tags: file-geodatabase, data-management, schema-locks, schema

I have recently been able to add 2 layers to the Table of Contents is ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy. It uses code like this:

```py
ResultPath1 = r"*DirectFilePath*.gdb\GeocodedDonationLocations"

# Making Feature Layer from Feature Class, adding to map
layername = "Donation Locations"
layerfile1 = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(ResultPath1, layername)[0]
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"*DirectFilePath*.aprx")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
m.addLayer(layerfile1,"TOP")

ResultPath1 = r"*DirectFilePath*.gdb\GeocodedUserLocation"
layername = "User Location"
layerfile1 = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(ResultPath1, layername)[0]
m = p.listMaps()[0]
m.addLayer(layerfile1,"TOP")
```

So, I am thinking that the schema is there to get `arcpy.management` stuff like `MakeFeatureLayer` and `addLayer` work properly. I just cannot figure out how to get it to give up the lock.

I have run into some advice recommending using `Compact()` on the geodatabase, but I think that I would have to delete the entries from the TOC first, no? I have also run into folks who use `arcpy.DisconnectUser` - but that seems to be for Enterprise Geodatabases, and this is a simple File GeoDatabase.

In my head, I have an idea of duplicating the original layers in the TOC, then deleting the old ones. Not sure if that would work, however.

Comment: The schema lock is there because you're using the contents of the database, there is no way around it, the lock is given up when you're no longer using the contents of the database in *any* process... that's it, end of story. If you have the geodatabase open in multiple instances you will not be able to use operations like Add/Delete Field etc. The posts you have read about using Compact to release locks relate to schema locks from crashed/abandoned sessions.

Comment: Where is this code being run?  If it is stand-alone code being run outside of Pro, the schema locks will go away when the Python session ends.  If you are running it in a Pro session, why are you running code to modify an APRX file on disk within a Pro session for a different APRX?